# How to make a TableEditor editable when there is nothing in it

Tags: java, swt, jface

I am having a problem with the TableEditor in SWT. I am working from the code in this link:
http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet88.java

The code works pretty much perfect for what I want except for one thing. If the table has nothing in it, then I can't edit the column that I need to edit.

More specifically, I am using a TableViewer to populate the table with data from elsewhere in my code. If the table is populated with data from that other place then I can edit the value, but for some reason I can't edit the column when there is nothing in it (i.e. if I haven't already taken data from somewhere else). This is a pretty big drawback for me.

Hopefully it's just a matter of changing an attribute of the Editor, but I can't seem to find where/how to change it. Has anyone come across this problem before? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I think you should always add action data object into TableViewer to show the Actions ( Add, Delete...etc) in Table Column. Without data from your content provider, table will not render any cell related info.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would want to somehow hint the user there's a way to edit this. This can be achieved by adding a synthetic item in a table:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Eugene. I had thought of this alright, but the problem is that I have twelve tables in the software and each of them can also take their data from somewhere else in the software. Ideally I would like the user to be able to input the data either directly via the empty table OR from the other place in the software. Is there a way to put the synthetic item in the table without filling the software with dummy variables?

Comment: I cannot think of any such way in JFace. I would try creating something like a decorating content provider (it would forward the call to fetch children of the root to the delegate and return synthetic node when there are no children) - similar, label provider, cell editor, etc. could also be decorated to support these nodes. Still 12 locations in the source code to modify though...